How to have a new instance of my program for each test?
I am an experienced Ethereum developer, new to Solana, so this question may be framed incorrectly. However, when writing tests in Eth dev, its easy to redeploy your contracts (programs) before each test to have a clean set to work with and set up the specific conditions you are testing. This is partly because the Ethereum equivalent of the program ID is generated at the time of deployment, meaning there's no conflicts.
However in Solana, given that the program ID is generated beforehand, the re-deployed code will conflict with the old code.
So my question is, what can I do in a beforeEach / afterEach so that within each test I have a freshly deployed instance of my program? I'm happy to completely nuke the test validator after each test if that's what's required, but not sure how to do that from within the tests.
I am using Anchor (@coral-xyz/anchor) and Mocha for my tests.

When you use anchor test it does always start a new test validator for you automatically so you should not have that problem.
In the anchor.toml you can tell it to use localnet instead of devnet.
You can also use anchor bankrun which works directly on the bank, runs faster and give you options like time travel:
https://github.com/kevinheavey/anchor-bankrun
https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/
You can find some exaples for that in the Solana Bootcamp:
https://github.com/solana-developers/developer-bootcamp-2024
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amAq-WHAFs8&ab_channel=Solana
Here is another video explaining testing with bankrun:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rut9l6nPZls&t=7s&ab_channel=SolPlay

the thing i wanted was for it to reset the contract before each individual tests, not before the entire test suite. so anchor in its default state is not fit for purpose, but i looked into bankrun and have managed to get it to give me a fresh chain before each test. so marking this as the correct answer but want to highlight for future readers that only the second part of the answer is correct.
